# .Column and .Row as integers

Tags: excel, vba

I came across runtime error 91: object or variable not set. I understand this error appears when variables are misdeclared, but how? C is a cell, and both column and row position return integers.

```
Sub Subroutine_1()

Dim C As Range

Dim column_Position As Integer

Dim row_Position As Integer


With Range("a1:f50")
      Set C = .Find("f-value", LookIn:=xlValues)
      column_Position = C.Column
      row_Position = C.Row
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Find returns `Nothing` if no match is found - `Nothing` does not have any properties such as Row/Column.   It's a good practice to always check you got a match from `Find`, using something like `If Not C Is Nothing Then`

Comment: You may also want to get into the habit of using a `Long` variable instead when using it for something like a `Row`